# xcodebuild: error: The flag -scheme is required when specifying -archivePath but not -exportArchive

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, jenkins, xcode8

I am building ios app using Jenkins server running on AWS ec2 instance having Ubuntu. I am using Xcode plugin and added slave node of MacBookPro Laptop ! 
getting error please help :

```
xcodebuild: error: The flag -scheme is required when specifying -archivePath but not -exportArchive
```

As I am new to IOS build I really not able to figure out what is missing, as I am able to run code using Xcode from the laptop

My Xcode version is 8.2.1

Jenkins Console Output

```
Started by user Ashish Karpe
[EnvInject] - Loading node environment variables.
Building remotely on DevOps_MAC_slavenode (ios) in workspace /Users/Compumatrice/Jenkins/Home/workspace/DevOps_ios_build
 > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git config remote.origin.url https://github.com/compumatrice/PatientPortal.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/compumatrice/PatientPortal.git
 > git --version # timeout=10
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials 
 > git fetch --tags --progress https://github.com/compumatrice/PatientPortal.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/develop^{commit} # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/origin/develop^{commit} # timeout=10
Checking out Revision 0bb3c9595af72690f309618512191636959ec62b (refs/remotes/origin/develop)
Commit message: "Merge pull request #1091 from compumatrice/PatientPortal_yingale1March2017"
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f 0bb3c9595af72690f309618512191636959ec62b
 > git rev-list 0bb3c9595af72690f309618512191636959ec62b # timeout=10
[DevOps_ios_build] $ /bin/bash -xe /var/folders/6q/_jv3_5x553x2xyfsj99k56l40000gn/T/jenkins3534950859644223172.sh
+ security unlock-keychain -p 12345678 /Users/Compumatrice/Library/Keychains/DevOps_jenkins.keychain
Working directory is /Users/Compumatrice/Jenkins/Home/workspace/DevOps_ios_build.
[DevOps_ios_build] $ /usr/bin/xcodebuild -version
Xcode 8.2.1
Build version 8C1002
Fetching marketing version number (CFBundleShortVersionString) from project.
[DevOps_ios_build] $ /usr/bin/agvtool mvers -terse1
No marketing version found (CFBundleShortVersionString).
Marketing version (CFBundleShortVersionString) found in project configuration: .
Fetching technical version number (CFBundleVersion) from project.
[DevOps_ios_build] $ /usr/bin/agvtool vers -terse
No marketing version found (CFBundleVersion)
Technical version (CFBundleVersion) found in project configuration: .
Marketing version (CFBundleShortVersionString) used by Jenkins to produce the IPA: 
Technical version (CFBundleVersion) used by Jenkins to produce the IPA: 
[DevOps_ios_build] $ /usr/bin/security list-keychains -s /Users/Compumatrice/Library/Keychains/DevOps_jenkins.keychain
[DevOps_ios_build] $ /usr/bin/security default-keychain -d user -s /Users/Compumatrice/Library/Keychains/DevOps_jenkins.keychain
[DevOps_ios_build] $ /usr/bin/security unlock-keychain -p ******** /Users/Compumatrice/Library/Keychains/DevOps_jenkins.keychain
[DevOps_ios_build] $ /usr/bin/security show-keychain-info /Users/Compumatrice/Library/Keychains/DevOps_jenkins.keychain
Keychain "/Users/Compumatrice/Library/Keychains/DevOps_jenkins.keychain" lock-on-sleep timeout=300s
===========================================================
== Available provisioning profiles
[DevOps_ios_build] $ /usr/bin/security find-identity -p codesigning -v
  1) 859EC9B613EC5DCF23409F079EF61824C8569B3D "iPhone Developer: ashish.karpe@compumatrice.com (597YWUA3P2)"
  2) 45B0C2100F146938D957476F1E593AC6D91F85B6 "Mac Developer: ashish.karpe@compumatrice.com (597YWUA3P2)"
     2 valid identities found
== Can we find the requested provisioning profile ?
[DevOps_ios_build] $ /usr/bin/security find-certificate -a -c ashish.karpe@compumatrice.com -Z | grep ^SHA-1
== Available SDKs
[DevOps_ios_build] $ /usr/bin/xcodebuild -showsdks
iOS SDKs:
    iOS 10.2                        -sdk iphoneos10.2

iOS Simulator SDKs:
    Simulator - iOS 10.2            -sdk iphonesimulator10.2

macOS SDKs:
    macOS 10.12                     -sdk macosx10.12

tvOS SDKs:
    tvOS 10.1                       -sdk appletvos10.1

tvOS Simulator SDKs:
    Simulator - tvOS 10.1           -sdk appletvsimulator10.1

watchOS SDKs:
    watchOS 3.1                     -sdk watchos3.1

watchOS Simulator SDKs:
    Simulator - watchOS 3.1         -sdk watchsimulator3.1

== Available schemes
[DevOps_ios_build] $ /usr/bin/xcodebuild -list
Information about workspace "DevOps_ios_build":
    Schemes:
        PatientPortal
        CordovaLib
        Cordova


===========================================================
Going to invoke xcodebuild:target: , sdk: DEFAULT, project: DEFAULT, configuration: Release, clean: NO, archive:YES, symRoot: DEFAULT, buildDir: /Users/Compumatrice/Jenkins/Home/workspace/DevOps_ios_build/build, developmentTeamID: ashish.karpe@compumatrice.com
[DevOps_ios_build] $ /usr/bin/xcodebuild -target  -configuration Release archive -archivePath /Users/Compumatrice/Jenkins/Home/workspace/DevOps_ios_build/build/.xcarchive BUILD_DIR=/Users/Compumatrice/Jenkins/Home/workspace/DevOps_ios_build/build DEVELOPMENT_TEAM=ashish.karpe@compumatrice.com
xcodebuild: error: The flag -scheme is required when specifying -archivePath but not -exportArchive.
Cleaning up previously generated .ipa files
Cleaning up previously generated .dSYM.zip files
Packaging IPA
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Comment: what is the plugin's name and the plugin's version you are using?

Comment: @Daij-Djan Considering that you are asking about Jenkins plugin : https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Xcode+Plugin   ie  
Xcode integration 2.0.0
This plugin provides builders to build xcode projects, invoke agvtool and package .ipa files